# Python and pytest testing

Tags: python, pytest

I have to do some testing using pytest, but I have no idea where to start.
Here is piece of a code which i would like to test:

```
def print_url_and_id():
    for item in movie_link[:100]:
        print item.contents[1], "The ID of this movie is:", '"' + item.contents[1]['href'][7:16] + '"'
```

Could anyone tell me how it suppose to look like?

Comment: you should probably start with digging into unit testing procedure itself https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing

Comment: please make your code as code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import pytest


def parametrized():
    expected_results = ["movie_link_01", "movie_link_02"]
    movie_link = ["movie_link_01", "movie_link_02", "movie_link_03"]
    # you can define your new_movie_link list like this as you have done, but instead of
    # printing it, add it to a this new_movie_link list
    return [(item_1, item_2) for item_1, item_2 in zip(movie_link[:2], expected_results)]


@pytest.mark.parametrize("movie_link, expected", parametrized())
def test_parametrizer(movie_link, expected):
    assert movie_link == expected
```